# How do I connect to Oracle with SSIS? I am getting the error: "tns listener was not given the service_name in connect_data"

Tags: oracle, ssis, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB through the Oracle Provider for OLE DB in SSIS, but am getting the following error when testing the connection: "tns listener was not given the service_name in connect_data". I am not too familiar with Oracle, so could someone provide me some direction for how to fix this error?

Answer (score 11):

You can add the service name after the host name with a forward slash between them. This has worked in both the Microsoft and Oracle OLE DB providers.

[image: Oracle SQL Developer Connection Properties]

[image: Visual Studio Connection Properties]

IP/Service_Name also works, "12.12.123.123/Server1.domain.com"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, always use Oracle driver. Not the Microsoft one.

Then, when connecting, supply the TNSNAME, USERNAME and PASSWORD to a OLEDB Connection.

That's all!

Comment: Would the TNS Name just be the server and DB name that you're trying to connect to?

Comment: TNSName is an alias to the servername, port, etc. It is located in your Oracle home directory under \Network\Admin\ in a file usually called TNSNAMES.ora

Comment: OK I have added the connection to the TNSNAMES.ora file, and I am able to get a response from the command line when I ping that connection name, and I can successfully add this connection to Oracle SQL developer. But when I try to connect to this via SSIS, I get the following error - TNS Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor. Do you know how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok, been here, and this is what works:

You need oracle data access components http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Download the one that applies to you (11g, 12c...)
It installs an OLE DB provider which is FAST and also .NET connectors (wich also work really well), so I recommend using OLEDB (also, attunity connector works wonders aswell after you installed ODAC).

Then just connect using ip/service name + credentials, for example

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIr2u.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to type "Servername/ServiceName" to Server Name Field .