# Trouble connecting to Oracle DB from SSIS 2008?

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssis-2008

I know that there are tons of similar questions, but I checked most of them and they didn't shed any light on the issue I'm having.

I'm creating an SSIS package with VS 2008, and I'm using the Connection Manager to create the connection.

I created `Sales.ora` that looks like this. This is the connection info that I use to connect via `Toad Data Point` (although I don't use the ORA file for Toad):

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=sl1.server.com)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=SALES)))
```

I'm posting screenshots of the errors I'm receiving:

[image]

If I enter the information directly, I receive error: `ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA`. I read this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199181/how-do-i-connect-to-oracle-with-ssis-i-am-getting-the-error-tns-listener-was) but there's no place for entering *Service Name*

[image: here]

If I use `Sales.ora` I get error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SERVICE_DATA should be placed in the CONNECT_DATA section

```
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = yaddayadda)
)
```

Try using the name of the database for the service_name.

Also, try giving it a hand and only filling the username section like this:

```
USERNAME/PASSWORD@DATABASE
```

For more information on the error you've found, you can read up [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12504_tns_listener_not_given_sid.htm)